# How do I take a UIView with a background pattern set and shrink it down vertically with an animation

Tags: ios, uiview, uianimation

I want the top of the view to meet the bottom of the view in a quick animation for its disappearance. (Preferably have it grow for a second first.)

How would I go about doing this? The UIView has a background pattern set with `[UIColor colorWithPattern:]`, and when I do `self.textOptionsPopover.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0.0, 0.5);`, it just disappears completely.

Comment: Have you tried a UIView animation block?

Comment: Not yet, as the even transforming it to 50% height makes it disappear. Not much sense animating that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have wrong x scale parameter - `CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0.0, 0.5)`
Change to `CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.0, 0.5)`, cause you don't want to modify your width.

0.0 is the reason that your view is disappearing.

But if you prefer to make it growing for a while first, it would be easier to use CAKeyframeAnimation - you can easly control key-times, values and timing functions. For example you can do something like this:

```
CAKeyframeAnimation *shrinkAnimation = [CAKeyframeAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform"];
shrinkAnimation.values = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                          [NSValue valueWithCATransform3D:CATransform3DMakeScale(1.0, 1.0, 1.0)],
                          [NSValue valueWithCATransform3D:CATransform3DMakeScale(1.0, 1.4, 1.0)],
                          [NSValue valueWithCATransform3D:CATransform3DMakeScale(1.0, 0.0, 1.0)],
                          nil];
shrinkAnimation.keyTimes = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@0.0, @0.2, @1.0, nil];
shrinkAnimation.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseIn];
shrinkAnimation.duration = 0.4;
shrinkAnimation.removedOnCompletion = NO;
shrinkAnimation.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards;
[self. textOptionsPopover.layer addAnimation:shrinkAnimation forKey:@"shrink"];
```

Edited:
If you want the view to shrink "from top to bottom", just change the anchor point of the layer (remember that changing anchor point will change the frame!):

```
CGRect frame = self.textOptionsPopover.layer.frame;
self.textOptionsPopover.layer.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0.5, 1.0);
self.textOptionsPopover.layer.frame = frame;
```

Comment: Ah. But it still resizes it by bringing the bottom to the top, I want the opposite, how do I achieve that?

Comment: If I correctly understand your point, just change the anchor point of the layer - see my edition above.

Comment: I... wow. What an answer. I love the key frame things, it's much easier than I thought it would be! Only issue is that your animation shrinks the top and bottom both to the middle. For mine I want the bottom to stay exactly where it is. Is that possible?

Comment: Yep, I wrote it in the edit as I said - just change the anchor point to CGPointMake(0.5, 1.0); and your view will start to shrink with bottom in the same place.

Answer (score 0):

You could change the frame size and animate that. 
For example

Suppose finalFrameSize is a CGRect for the final value, you could get the animation effect like this.

```
 [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3f
                  animations:^{
                                 currentView.frame = finalFrameSize;
                             }
                             completion:^(BOOL finished){
                                 // Do something after the animation is comlete
                             }];
```